# How do I earn Light Up the Level in Iron Snout?

Tags: achievements, iron-snout

How do you obtain the *Light Up the Level* Achievement in Iron Snout? (Steam- PC)

Its described as doing 'Activate both lamps during a fight' but I cant get any of the lamps to light up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to knock a wolf into it. Usually, crouch, then hit left/right up up to knock a wolf in the air, then left/right again to knock them. They have to hit the lamp. It zaps them for about 3-5 seconds, <strike>so you have to be quick with it</strike>

**edit:** The lamps don't have to be lit at the same time - just in the same fight.

Source: just unlocked it

Comment: are you  using a controller? I cant seem to achieve it through the keyboard

Comment: I used a keyboard. Clicking up to launch them into the air then at the top height, left or right to launch them into the lamp.